# unicode in webClient.DownloadString() and insert html to literal

Tags: asp.net, unicode, utf-8

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        result = client.DownloadString(TextBox1.Text );
    }

  literal.text=result;
```

how can Unicode the `result`;
utf-8

2.

If www.google.com in the address bar to enter the page. loading speed is equal when the code is written(result)

how can faster this way.(result)

3.

```
literal.text=result
```

sqy error:Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.f.q' is null or not an object

result="....."
i think this error for `<html></htm>` and `<body></body>`

Comment: yes i want to encode the result as utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    byte[] byteA = new byte[99999];

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        byteA  = client.DownloadData(TextBox1.Text );    
    }
```

DownloadData resolve utf-8

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the `result` to UTF-8:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result)
```